# Is there a performance difference between str_replace and str_ireplace?

Tags: php, performance

Is there a performance difference between str_replace and str_ireplace?

If yes, in favour of which function and why?

Comment: Have you tried testing it instead of asking here? Might be faster.

Comment: Not so as you'd notice even over millions of executions

Comment: @Daan as testing would require considering multiple parameters like length of haystack and needle, and others, my limited expertise doesn't allow me to know, it was definitely faster to type the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str_ireplace` imposes a little overhead because it needs to convert both "haystack" and "needle" to lowercase before comparison. ([c source](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/standard/string.c#php_str_to_str_ex)) However, since this conversion is ascii-only, it's lighting fast and won't affect performance in any noticeable way.

Here's a little test:

```
for($i = 2; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $x = str_repeat('a', pow(10, $i));
    $t = microtime(1); str_replace ('a', 'b', $x); $a = microtime(1) - $t;
    $t = microtime(1); str_ireplace('A', 'b', $x); $b = microtime(1) - $t;
    $t = microtime(1); strtolower($x);             $c = microtime(1) - $t;
    printf("%d replace=%.4f ireplace=%.4f lower=%.4f\n", $i, $a, $b, $c);

}
```

Results:

```
2 replace=0.0000 ireplace=0.0000 lower=0.0000
3 replace=0.0000 ireplace=0.0000 lower=0.0000
4 replace=0.0002 ireplace=0.0003 lower=0.0001
5 replace=0.0021 ireplace=0.0030 lower=0.0008
6 replace=0.0253 ireplace=0.0441 lower=0.0110
```

So, for a string of 1,000,000 characters `str_ireplace` is only 0.02 sec "slower". My suggestion is to optimize other parts of your program first ))

Answer (score 3):

The `str_ireplace` function php is not sensitive rule and will treat "abc","ABC"all combination as a single match. Is available in PHP 5 only.

The `str_replace` function is a case sensitive which means that it replaces the string that exactly matches the string exactly.

The `str_ireplace` will be less faster becuse  it need to convert to the same case. But the difference will be very little event in a large data.

Comment: > The str_ireplace will be faster becuse it doesn't spend time on case sensivity.
___

But there are more operations, as I would imagine both strings have to be converted to, say, lower case while the original strings are used when case sensitive.